# Crash após ler valor com scanf

Tags: c

Primeiramente, sou "noob" em programação. Comecei a faculdade hoje, e a matéria já estava rolando(terceira chamada tem suas consequências =P). O código é simples, o terceira que criei, entretanto, depois de compilar e escrever um valor, o CMD para de funcionar.

O código em si é:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main (void) 
{
    int sal, novo_sal;
    printf ("Entre com sal");
    scanf ("%d, &sal");
    if (sal >= 1000) {
        novo_sal = 1.1 * sal;
        printf ("%d", novo_sal);
    }
    else { 
        novo_sal = 1.2 * sal;
        printf ("%d", novo_sal);
    }
}
```

Minha pergunta é: Tem algo errado com o código, ou com o compilador?

Answer (score 7):

Eu suponho que você tenha querido dizer

```
scanf ("%d", &sal);
```

no lugar de

```
scanf ("%d, &sal");
```

O primeiro diz: "Leia um número e coloque na variável `sal`".

O segundo diz: "Leia um número seguido de `", &sal"` e coloque esse número em um lugar não especificado da memória".

Escrever em pedaços 'aleatórios' da memória geralmente vai te causar um crash por estar escrevendo em uma área que você não poderia escrever.

Compilando esse código com o GCC, tenho o seguinte diagnóstico:

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:7:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]
     scanf ("%d, &sal");
     ^
```

Dê sempre atenção a qualquer alerta que o seu compilador te der. E de preferência compile com um nível bastante elevado de alertas. Isso é importante especialmente se você estiver começando. Para o GCC a opção é `-Wall -Wextra`. Vai variar dependendo do compilador que você está a usar.

Answer (score 2):

Outra dica: mude o tipo da variável novo_sal para float. Assim você terá uma resposta mais precisa no output do seu programa. Mais informações [aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).
O código final ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   int sal;
   float novo_sal;
   printf ("Entre com sal");
   scanf ("%d", &sal);
   if (sal >= 1000) {
      novo_sal = 1.1 * sal;
      printf ("%f \n", novo_sal);
   }
   else {
      novo_sal = 1.2 * sal;
       printf ("%f \n", novo_sal);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problema:**

---

> `scanf ("%d, &sal");`  <- Você não pode deixar todo o conteúdo do
>   `scanf` dentro de aspas.

---

**Correção:**

---

> `scanf ("%d", &sal);` <- A variável que vai receber o valor de `input`
>   não pode estar dentro de aspas. `&sal`

---

**Obervação:** Não deixar variáveis dentro de aspas, caso contrario elas serão tradas como um simples "Texto".